# How to implement morris.js to laravel dompdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-snappy

[bladepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZgtj.png)I have installed laravel 5.8 and installed barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package. I have used some jquery chart plugin to show chart on blade file, it's works fine. By using dompdf package , I am trying to shown this piechart on pdf, but chart's are not showing on pdf. How to show charts on pdf, Is there any solution to show charts on streaming/download pdf.?

I want to attach the above blade file to my PDF

**My second Question:**

I have installed laravel-snappy 
and i got below error while generating pdf.....

The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%\r[======>                                                     ] 10%\r[=======>                 ▶
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing\r[============================================================] Page 1 of 1\rDone       ▶
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolFailure
"
stdout: ""
command: C:\xampp\htdocs\geetha\vendor\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --enable-javascript --javascript-delay "5000" --enable-smart-shrinking --no-stop ▶
"""

Is there any solution to show charts on streaming/download pdf.?

Comment: Did you try to export your generated chart to image and then include it in your PDF template? And please provide name of jQuery plugin you used and part of your code.

Comment: I'm using morris.js plugin then how to convert chart to image file

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647395/saving-morris-charts-to-image-using-html2canvas